# Set <td> with the data inside to static width and height

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have a table that displays dynamic data from the DB, The data could contain images, videos, iframes, tables, text ..etc.

I'm using DataTables jQuery library: http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Live fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y1u0vb86/8/

Here is an example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>FirstHeading</td>
    </tr>
  </thead> <!-- thead -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="truncate">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum itaque, sint impedit recusandae sunt, vel quod optio voluptas laudantium doloremque aspernatur deleniti autem delectus expedita veritatis explicabo quidem perspiciatis sapiente praesentium, ratione. Beatae praesentium possimus explicabo, rerum quia architecto itaque a vero odio dolores saepe quisquam, natus vel eos veniam id voluptatum harum iusto corporis. Facilis neque, cum corporis debitis suscipit veritatis quod! Harum iste sequi cum accusantium magni facere sunt assumenda impedit eveniet, veniam laudantium obcaecati quo, labore error reprehenderit quod, doloremque. Iusto fugit, libero minima tempora vitae iste rem, magnam sint explicabo quas tempore natus possimus reprehenderit ab, inventore.
        <img src="//placehold.it/200x200/100" > <!-- image -->
        <img src="//placehold.it/200x200/200" > <!-- image -->
      </td> <!-- .truncate -->
    </tr>
  </tbody> <!-- tbody -->
</table> <!-- table -->
```

The `<td>` which contains the data has the following class `class="truncate"`, I use that class to limit the height and the width of the `<td>`, Because if I don't do that the table width would exceed the window size and the height would be very long.

The styles for that class:

```
.truncate{
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The content contains HTML elements `<p> <img> <table> <iframe> ..etc` and these elements contain some dimensions in the html code like `<img style="width: 500px; height: 300px" src="">`, So I tried to style these elements:

```
.tuncate img,
.truncate table,
.truncate iframe,
.truncate video{
  max-height: 5px;
}
```

But the height is still long, I want the whole `<td>` not to exceed `50px` whatever elements inside it.

Comment: Maybe there are still some elements which have height greater than `td`. Probably you can apply max-height to all the elements. `.truncate * {
  max-height: 5px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In the td have a div that has max-height:50px, not the td.

```
<td>
  <div style="max-height:50px">whatever content...</div>
</td>
```